# Multiple results with VBA Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have got two sheets, one with data like this:

[image: Data 1]

For one person there can be couple of rows with answers.

And second sheet with this data:

[image: Data 2]

Here one person had only one row with answers.

Based on the surnames from second table I want to search the person in first table and if the person is present copy the whole row to another sheet. So my final output table will looks like this:

[image: Output]

My idea is that the algorithm should take the surname from table in Data 2 sheet on look for it in Data 1 sheet if is present then copy whole row into A3 Output sheet, next search the rest of Data 2 for another appearance. If blank cell then take another surname from Data 2 table and do it up to the point where in Data 2 table blank space is detected. But I have no idea how to translate it into VBA code.

Could anyone help with some clues? Or macro that I can use here?

I would be really thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VBA subroutine that I believe will do what you asked, not sure if it is what you want.  This is assuming you already have a tab to receive the data to be copied; the tabs being used are MRWV1 = names to select, MRWV2 = Data sheet of rows to copy and MRWV3 = sheet to receive the copied data.

```
    Sub MRWV()
    '
    ' MRWV Macro
    '
    '   Housekeeping
        vFoundKt = 1
        vSourceRows = 0
        vDataRows = 0
    '   Select the sheet with the five rows with the names to select
        Sheets("MRWV1").Select
        vSourceRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("MRWV2").Select
        vDataRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Get names from source sheet
        For iSource = 2 To vSourceRows
            Sheets("MRWV1").Select
            Range("A" & iSource).Select
            vSourceName1 = ActiveCell.Value
            Range("B" & iSource).Select
            vSourceName2 = ActiveCell.Value
            'Look through data sheet for matching names
            For iData = 2 To vDataRows
                Sheets("MRWV2").Select
                Range("A" & iData).Select
                vDataName1 = ActiveCell.Value
                Range("B" & iData).Select
                vDataName2 = ActiveCell.Value
                If vSourceName1 = vDataName1 And vSourceName2 = vDataName2 Then
                    vFoundKt = vFoundKt + 1
                    Range("A" & iData & ":I" & iData).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("MRWV3").Select
                    Range("C" & vFoundKt).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot! I've got only one issue. It's looking only for exact values in two cells, but in my data in MRWV1 there can be name starting with capital and in MRWV2 the same name starting with minuscule. Is there any simple method to implement to the macro to detecting it like the same values or maybe writing another macro to change first letters in all cells to capital is easier?

Comment: Ok, I manage to repair this problem by replacing the comparison part by If (StrComp(vSourceName1, vDataName1, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then ...

Comment: Nice repair, my first thought was to use an upshift on all variables to eliminate case, yours is more elegant.

Comment: Now I have another problem. I want to do the same, but I have also value Date. so I'm taking names from MRWV1 and searching for them in MRWV2 and comparing: firstly the names should be equal and if date from MRWV1 is older than in MRWV2 then delete whole row with this name from MRWV1. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but with questions. I'm assuming the entries in MRWV1 (Source) are not repeated, or if they are repeated then the date should be in the comparison to prevent replications in the copy to the third tab.  If you do delete the row in the source, then would need to exit the loop.  If there are multiple dates in the comparison tab (MRWV2) then what happens if you find newer AND older dates - do you still want to delete?  Please let me know.